# EF Core can't evaluate an expression value .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Why EF Core can't evaluate this value

```
{log => (True AndAlso Invoke(log => log.Message.StartsWith("test"), log))}
```

and It gives me this error :
**"The LINQ expression 'log' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'."**
While this expression runs normally :

```
{log => (True AndAlso Invoke(log => log.Message.StartsWith(value(Project.Logging.Specs+<> c__DisplayClass1_1).message), log))}
```

This happens when I add 2 expression together using `AndAlso` Extension Method

```
Expression<Func<Logs, bool>> exp1 = log => true;
Expression<Func<Logs, bool>> exp2 = log => log.Message.Contains("message");

exp1 = exp1.AndAlso(exp);

public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndAlso<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> left, Expression<Func<T, bool>> right)
{
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(right, left.Parameters);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(left.Body, invokedExpr), left.Parameters);
}
```

And finally I call dbContext

```
_context
  .Logs
  .Where(exp1);
```

Comment: please share the actual code...

Comment: That usually means the code (query conditions) you wrote isn't supported by EF. EF needs to take your C# code and translate them to SQL, if it doesn't know how to translate, this exception will happen. Post the actual `.Where(...)` C# code, so we can see if it's fixable.

Comment: Looks like you are combining two lambdas via Expression.Invoke?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yes, I will add the code now too.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what syntax is `(True AndAlso Invoke(...))`? I've never seen that before. I note that `AndAlso` is a VB.NET operator, not a C# operator...

Comment: @Dai Sorry, it's my fault. ```AndAlso``` is an extension method I made, I just provided its code. This syntax happens when you add 2 expressions together using Expression.Invoke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looked for duplicate, but found something outdated.
For EF Core you can use `ReplacingExpressionVisitor` from `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal` namespace.

```cs
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndAlso<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> left, Expression<Func<T, bool>> right)
{
    var visitor = new ReplacingExpressionVisitor(right.Parameters, left.Parameters);

    var rightBody = visitor.Visit(right.Body);
    var newPredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(left.Body, rightBody), left.Parameters);

    return newPredicate;
}
```

Comment: `var visitor = new ReplacingExpressionVisitor(right.Parameters, left.Parameters);`
This lines gives me an error **cannot convert from System.Linq.Expressions.ParamterExpression to System.Linq.Expressions.Expression[]**

Comment: @Jawoy, probably in your project you already have `ReplacingExpressionVisitor` which replaces one parameter. EF Core`s visitor accepts [collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.query.replacingexpressionvisitor.-ctor?view=efcore-7.0) of expressions

Comment: I found a class called `ExpressionVisitor` and I did a logic similar to what you gave me and it works. Thanks alot.